# android - Theme.Holo with DarkActionBar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar, themes

in my app I want to use `Theme.Holo` but with the *DarkActionBar* from `Theme.Holo.Light`. I was trying to change the background (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) but it didn't worked properly. Here's the code I've tried to get working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But I'm not sure about that `<item name="android:background">@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar</item>`, as **Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar** is not a background (from what I know).

I'm also not aware of any other solution, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem ? What do you mean by "it didn't work properly" ? Do you've minSDKVersion set to >=3.0 already ?

Comment: So, for what I understood of your question, do you want Theme.Holo on your app with dark action bar?? Is it not redundant what you're doing? Holo already comes with dark action bar.
Is that what you want? Am I getting it right?

Comment: @CarlosJimenez It's a long time ago, but I still have the problem. I want the same dark action bar that is used in the KitKat Android Settings. It looks bit different from the Theme.Holo one.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the default color of the dark action bar (#2d2d2d) and get rid of the Inverse part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">#2d2d2d</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it in a few hours